# Javascript Callback Not Working as Intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to ensure that `checkteamexists` only executes after `checklogin` has executed. However, `checkteamexists` still functions after `checklogin`.

You can imagine `teamhome1_message` and `teamhome2_message` as alert dialogs. They pop a message up and didn't return anything.

```js
function pushhistory(url, callback) {
  history.push(url);
  callback();
}

function checklogin(callback) {
  if (!state.user.authenticated) {
    pushhistory("/accounts/login", function() {
      teamhome2_message()
    });
  }
  callback();
}

function checkteamexists(teamname) {
  if (teamname.toString().toLowerCase() == "team1") {
    teamid = 1;
  }
  else {
    pushhistory("/", function() {
      teamhome1_message()
    });
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  checklogin(function() {
    checkteamexists(teamname);
  })
}, []);
```

`checklogin` worked because the URL became `/accounts/login` and prompted `teamhome2_message`. However, `teamhome1_message` still appeared even though I don't want it to.

I tried specifying a callback in the `useEffect` hook (which is specific to React) but the callback didn't seem to work either. Can anyone please point out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try put `callback();` in else block in checklogin

Comment: `didn't return anything` - you have absolutely no `return` statements in your code - so, of course none of the functions you've shown will `return` anything

Comment: According to your flow :  unless this is true (teamname.toString().toLowerCase() == "team1") , teamhome1_message  will always be called.

Comment: @JaromandaX I did not intend to return anything nor retrieve any returned value; the problem was regarding callbacks and I'd just like to make clear that none of the functions will return anything. Apologize if my question is described unclearly.

Comment: @TusharShahi I want `teamhome1_message` to be called in the else block... my problem ended up being that I did not place my callback block correctly.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted a return value, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@p2pdops had the right solution: put the `callback` function in the else block.